# Why does this snippet for fallback-sourcing a mixed list of Puppet templates/files not work?

Tags: puppet

This seems to sit between the domains of stackoverflow and serverfault, but it seems ultimately a devel issue, so am posting it here.

In order to make my Puppet tree a bit more DRY (while avoiding enormous if-else ladders and hacky "/dev/null" fallbacks in my manifests), I want to be able to just call a function with a mixed list of templates/files to lookup in order, and use (and expand if necessary) the first one found. I wrote the code below heavily based on some ancient code (see the commented line for the link to that). I can't see why it doesn't yet work, and would appreciate if anyone can find what I've missed (or misunderstood).

I am ensuring:

- Apache (and Passenger sub-process) are restarted on the master (to pick up the new function) before running puppet on the client
- the client is run with --pluginsync

and I have already unsuccessfully tried:

- using `wrapper.file = filepath` instead of `wrapper.file = filename`

and many other things, which I won't list as they seemed to have been red herrings. I found one email-thread which hinted that such code would only run on the client, whereas it of course needs to run on the master, but I can see the original code from the pastie link has worked successfully for others, and my changes shouldn't make any difference to the client/master aspect of that.

<del>I am running puppet v3.7 on the client and v2.7 on the master (long story short - I can't avoid this for now,</del> (*see EDIT3 below*) but I think the important point is that they are both >= 2.6, regarding the `environment.to_s` change).

I call the function with:

```
$sshd_config_content = multi_source_mixed("template|ssh/sshd_config.${::fqdn}.erb", "file|ssh/sshd_config.${::fqdn}", "template|ssh/sshd_config.${::domain}.erb", "file|ssh/sshd_config.${::domain}", "template|ssh/sshd_config.${::hostname}.erb", "file|ssh/sshd_config.${::hostname}", 'template|ssh/sshd_config.erb', 'file|ssh/sshd_config')
```

and always get the error:

```
Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on SERVER: multi_source_mixed: No match found for files/templates: template|ssh/sshd_config.XXX.erb, file|ssh/sshd_config.XXX, template|ssh/sshd_config.XX.erb, file|ssh/sshd_config.XX, template|ssh/sshd_config.X.erb, file|ssh/sshd_config.X, template|ssh/sshd_config.erb, file|ssh/sshd_config at /etc/puppet/environments/YYYY/modules/ZZZZ/manifests/init.pp:337 on node XXX
Warning: Not using cache on failed catalog
Error: Could not retrieve catalog; skipping run
```

My code (so far) is:

```
# adapted from template-only version at http://pastie.org/666728
# this doesn't yet work (for me)

module Puppet::Parser::Functions
  require 'erb'

  newfunction(:multi_source_mixed, :type => :rvalue) do |args|
    this_module = 'THIS_MODULE_NAME'
    contents = nil
    environment = compiler.environment.to_s
    sources = args

    sources.each do |file|
      if file.index('|')
        filetype, filename = file.split('|', 2)
      else
        filetype = 'file'
        filename = file
      end
      Puppet.debug("Looking for #{filetype} #{filename} in #{environment}")
      if filetype == 'template'
        if filepath = Puppet::Parser::Files.find_template(filename, environment)
          wrapper = Puppet::Parser::TemplateWrapper.new(self)
          wrapper.file = filename
          begin
            contents = wrapper.result
          rescue => detail
            raise Puppet::ParseError, "Failed to parse template %s: %s" % [filename, detail]
          end

          break
        end
      else
        filepath = Puppet::Module.find(this_module, environment).to_s + '/files/' + filename
        if File.file?(filepath)
          begin
            contents = File.open(filepath, "rb").read
          rescue => detail
            raise Puppet::ParseError, "Failed to get contents from file %s: %s" % [filename, detail]
          end
        end

        break
      end
    end

    if contents == nil
      raise Puppet::ParseError, "multi_source_mixed: No match found for files/templates: #{sources.join(', ')}"
    end

    contents
  end
end
```

**EDIT**: BTW - I know the files being sourced exist in the right place already, as what I am doing with this code is replacing existing code which has been working already, but is hardcoded to search for files only, using the following:

```
source => ["puppet:///modules/ZZZZ/ssh/sshd_config.${::fqdn}", "puppet:///modules/ZZZZ/ssh/sshd_config.${::domain}", "puppet:///modules/ZZZZ/ssh/sshd_config.${::hostname}", 'puppet:///modules/ZZZZ/ssh/sshd_config']
```

**EDIT 2**: <del>I proceeded with trying to test this using client=3.7 and master=2.7 because it is the only setup I can use for now, but I have since found several threads stating that it is painful-and-usually-impossible to even try to get an older puppetmaster version to cooperate with a newer puppetclient version, and I know at least one of the errors I've been ignoring for now has been to do with that. I suspect even some of this specific problem may be a consequence of that too, but unfortunately have no easy way to test things further until the upgrade of the master happens (probably won't happen for at least a week or two)</del> (see below)

**EDIT 3**: I am now testing it with client and master at v2.7, and the problem remains...

Comment: I cast a vote to close because you desperately need to condense your issue to the least amount of (Ruby) code that is necessary to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @FelixFrank: I didn't want to reduce the code further than that pasted above at first, as after investing quite a bit of time editing and reverting in circles, I had reached an impasse where I am not entirely sure which part of it is guilty (ruby is not my main forte), and I didn't want to commit the equally heinous crime of leaving out vital info. I would very much welcome input from anyone to help eliminate the parts which are definitely not causing the problem, if anyone has the patience...

Comment: The reason for the rule is that while condensing the code, you will likely find the cause for the issue yourself. A good way to debug Ruby stuff is `irb`, an interactive interpreter. Just launch it up, do `require puppet`, then start pasting snippets of your code, after supplying sensible variable values. Don't use `newfunction`, just recreate the body. I'd expect most if not all of that to work from `irb`.

Comment: @FelixFrank Thanks for the pointers. I'd already tried similar to what you suggest (& now tried exactly what you said) in irb, but always came up against things like `compiler` not defined when going that route (even from within the templatewrapper call), which is why I couldn't condense the code yet. Anyway, having just lost more time on it, I'll probably just find a less elegant workaround and leave the question to the whims of fate (I realise this isn't a support forum so won't ask for handholding with troubleshooting). It's just a shame because it'll bug me that I didn't "solve" it.